# Big-O of a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, big-o

I was wondering what the Big-O of this code snippet is

```
def clear_list(my_list):
    while len(my_list) > 0:
        my_list.pop(0)
    return my_list
```

Would it be O(n^2) or O(n) because the while loop is O(n) or O(1) and `pop(0)` is O(n) as well. I don't think the while loop is O(log n) since no value that is being compared in the while loop is cut in half.

Comment: The way it's currently written, it will return after the first `pop(0)` which means the function is O(1).

Comment: `pop()` is O(1): https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @BrentWashburne: but the `list.pop(0)` call is O(N).

Comment: If you are going to pop from the left, use a `collections.deque` because popleft for those is O(1). https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: What is the type of `my_list`?

Comment: @BillLynch A normal python list

Comment: @BrentWashburne Ah thanks for spotting that, I had the indent of the return wrong. EDITED thanks

Comment: `collections.deque` are optimized for adding  / removing from both ends.  Per the docs, pop(0) on a list is O(N).   https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is O(N^2):

- The while loop takes N steps, until all elements have been removed.
- `list.pop(0)` is O(N); all elements in the list following have to shift up one step. That the list is shortened each step still gives you an average of 1/2 N steps over the whole process, where the 1/2 can be ignored (it doesn't matter when viewed asymptotically).

Comment: @MartijnPieters you have to multiply the complexity of the while and the pop

Comment: If list.pop(0) is O(N) and you have it in a while loop, that makes it O(N^2)

Comment: @spirographer: The loop only ever takes 1 step, because `return` exits it.

Comment: @RobertB: no, because the while loop exits early.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry I had indented the return wrong. What would it be now?

Comment: @Jacklin213: ah, that was not helpful.

Comment: Might be worth noting in this answer that using a collections.deque instead of a list would change this to O(N) since the deque.popleft() is O(1).

Comment: @RobertB: feels a little too much out of scope here. It's fine in a comment on the question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I guess, but in the original question the data type was not specified, so I felt it was ambiguous. If you pass a `collections.deque` into the function `clear_list` as written, it would be O(N). If you pass a list into that exact same function, it is O(N^2). So the Omega of the function is ambigous. Thank you duck-typing.

Answer (score 3):

It's going to be O(n^2) because in the `while` loop you have to go through all n elements, and in the `pop` you have to shift all of the elements that follow the first element.

Here's a link to a related answer:
[What is the time complexity of popping elements from list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195625/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-popping-elements-from-list-in-python)

Comment: @MartijnPieters the return is not in the loop

Comment: That was a mistake from OP. This answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I just benchmarked this for you (EDIT: I assumed the return was misplaced since otherwise why do I even)

```
from time import time
def check(size):
    a = range(size)
    start = time()
    clear_list(a)
    return time() - start
check(40000) # About .4 seconds on my computer
check(80000) # About 1.6 seconds on my computer
```

Clearly O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark :) Helped me visualize it :)