# Combining three lists in Python with sorting

Tags: python, list

How to efficiently and smartly combine 3 lists in the way like below?

```
 sex = ['M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F']
 actresses = ['Natalie Portman', 'Anne Hathaway', 'Talia Shire', 'Diane Keaton', 'Keira Knightley', 'Uma Thurman']
 actors = ['Morgan Freeman', 'Leonardo DiCaprio', 'Robert De Niro', 'Brad Pitt']
```

Result:

```
[('M', 'Morgan Freeman'),
 ('M', 'Leonardo DiCaprio'),
 ('F', 'Natalie Portman'),
 ('F', 'Anne Hathaway'),
 ('M', 'Robert De Niro'),
 ('F', 'Talia Shire'),
 ('M', 'Brad Pitt'),
 ('F', 'Diane Keaton'),
 ('F', 'Keira Knightley'),
 ('F', 'Uma Thurman')]
```

My solution:

```
sex = ['M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F']
actresses = ['Natalie Portman', 'Anne Hathaway', 'Talia Shire', 'Diane Keaton', 'Keira Knightley', 'Uma Thurman', ]
actors = ['Morgan Freeman', 'Leonardo DiCaprio', 'Robert De Niro', 'Brad Pitt']
result = []

for s in sex:
    if s == 'F':
        result.append((s, actresses.pop(0)))
    elif s == 'M':
        result.append((s, actors.pop(0)))

print(f'result = {result}')
```

What is the best way for a long lists (e.g. 1 million items)?

Comment: Have you considered using pandas DataFrames? You could simply store the actresses into a dataframe, the actors into another dataframe, add a gender column to each dataframe (`df_actors['gender'] = 'M'` and `df_actresses['gender'] = 'F'`), and then merge the dataframes.

Comment: I think there is no better way. You have a O(N) algorithm, and for the problem's nature you have to check the sex array one by one.

Comment: `the best way` - I imagine the **best** way is one that works.

Comment: Use collections.deque instead of lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are popping from starting of the list which has [time complexity of O(N)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/195839/13123836). What you could do instead is keep an index for both `actors` and `actresses` lists and increment them in the loop.

```py
sex = ['M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F']
actresses = ['Natalie Portman', 'Anne Hathaway', 'Talia Shire', 'Diane Keaton', 'Keira Knightley', 'Uma Thurman', ]
actors = ['Morgan Freeman', 'Leonardo DiCaprio', 'Robert De Niro', 'Brad Pitt']
result = []

actors_i = 0
actresses_i = 0

for s in sex:
    if s == 'F':
        result.append((s, actresses[actresses_i]))
        actresses_i += 1
    elif s == 'M':
        result.append((s, actors[actors_i]))
        actors_i += 1

print(f'result = {result}')
```

After this point, I don't think there are any improvements left other than making your code more readable because you have to go over every item in the `sex` list and you are using operations which has cost of `O(1)` in the loop. So the complexity is `O(N)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can place references to the lists in a dictionary and do a list comprehension

```
In [8]: sexes = ['M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F'] 
   ...: actresses = ['Natalie Portman', 'Anne Hathaway', 'Talia Shire', 'Diane Keaton', 'Keira Knightley', 'Uma Thurman', ] 
   ...: actors = ['Morgan Freeman', 'Leonardo DiCaprio', 'Robert De Niro', 'Brad Pitt']
   ...: 
   ...: mf = {'M':iter(actors), 'F':iter(actresses)} 
   ...: [(sex, next(mf[sex])) for sex in sexes]                                                                                                 
Out[8]: 
[('M', 'Morgan Freeman'),
 ('M', 'Leonardo DiCaprio'),
 ('F', 'Natalie Portman'),
 ('F', 'Anne Hathaway'),
 ('M', 'Robert De Niro'),
 ('F', 'Talia Shire'),
 ('M', 'Brad Pitt'),
 ('F', 'Diane Keaton'),
 ('F', 'Keira Knightley'),
 ('F', 'Uma Thurman')]

In [9]:
```

If your list are longish and you are going to consume one pair sex-person at once you can use a generator expression in place of the list comprehension

```
pairs = ((sex, next(mf[s])) for sex in sexes)
for sex, person in pairs:
    ...
```

or possibly even simpler

```
for sex in sexes:
    person =  next(mf[sex])
    ...
```

If your lists were stored on disk you can use the same pattern introduced above but using generator expressions in place of lists

```
mf = {'M':(line.strip() for line in open('male_performers.txt'), 
      'F':(line.strip() for line in open('female_performers.txt')}
sexes = (line.strip() for line in open('sexes.txt'))

for sex in sexes:
     performer = next(mf[sex])
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that all actors have a label of 'M' and all actresses have a label of 'F', you could use pandas to group the information in a way that should have faster performance than looping through large lists.

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

actresses = ['Natalie Portman', 'Anne Hathaway', 'Talia Shire', 'Diane Keaton', 'Keira Knightley', 'Uma Thurman', ]
actors = ['Morgan Freeman', 'Leonardo DiCaprio', 'Robert De Niro', 'Brad Pitt']

df_actresses = pd.DataFrame(actresses, columns=['name'])
df_actors = pd.DataFrame(actors, columns=['name'])

df_actresses['sex'] = 'F'
df_actors['sex'] = 'M'

df = pd.concat([df_actresses, df_actors], axis=0)

# if you really need it to be a list
result = df.values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all the answers. Yes, using **pop(0)** was a very bad idea in this case. I tried to compare all solutions for 1 million pseudo items. In my opinion the results were very good except for the use of **pop(0)**.

Results:

```
combine_with_pop     Items = 1000000. Average time: 45.49504270553589 secs
combine_without_pop  Items = 1000000. Average time:  0.33301634788513185 secs
combine_dict         Items = 1000000. Average time:  0.21431212425231932 secs
combine_generator    Items = 1000000. Average time:  0.2770370960235596 secs
combine_frames       Items = 1000000. Average time:  0.06862187385559082 secs
```

Test:

```
import pandas as pd
import string
import random
import time
import inspect
from statistics import mean

result_size = 1000000
g_number_of_repetitions = 5


def init():
    # Generate sexes
    population = ('M', 'F')
    male_weight = 0.48
    weights = (0.4, 1 - male_weight)
    actresses = []
    actors = []
    sexes = random.choices(population, weights, k=result_size)
    male_amount = sexes.count('M')
    female_amount = result_size - male_amount

    # Generate pseudo 'actresses' and 'actors'
    act_len = 20
    for a in range(female_amount):
        actresses.append(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=act_len)))
    for a in range(male_amount):
        actors.append(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=act_len)))
    return sexes, actresses, actors


def combine_with_pop(number_of_repetitions, sexes, random_actresses, random_actors):
    time_measurements = []
    for i in range(number_of_repetitions):
        actors = random_actors[:]
        actresses = random_actresses[:]
        result = []
        t0 = time.time()
        for s in sexes:
            if s == 'F':
                result.append((s, actresses.pop(0)))
            elif s == 'M':
                result.append((s, actors.pop(0)))
        time_one_round = time.time() - t0
        time_measurements.append(time_one_round)
    print(
        f'{inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name.ljust(20)} '
        f'Items = {result_size}. Average time: {str(mean(time_measurements))} secs')


def combine_without_pop(number_of_repetitions, sexes, random_actresses, random_actors):
    time_measurements = []
    for i in range(number_of_repetitions):
        actors = random_actors[:]
        actresses = random_actresses[:]
        result = []
        actors_i = 0
        actresses_i = 0
        t0 = time.time()
        for s in sexes:
            if s == 'F':
                result.append((s, actresses[actresses_i]))
                actresses_i += 1
            elif s == 'M':
                result.append((s, actors[actors_i]))
                actors_i += 1
        time_one_round = time.time() - t0
        time_measurements.append(time_one_round)

    print(
        f'{inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name.ljust(20)} '
        f'Items = {result_size}. Average time: {str(mean(time_measurements))} secs')


def combine_dict(number_of_repetitions, sexes, random_actresses, random_actors):
    time_measurements = []
    for i in range(number_of_repetitions):
        actors = random_actors[:]
        actresses = random_actresses[:]
        result = []
        t0 = time.time()

        mf = {'M': iter(actors), 'F': iter(actresses)}
        result = [(sex, next(mf[sex])) for sex in sexes]
        time_one_round = time.time() - t0
        time_measurements.append(time_one_round)

    print(
        f'{inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name.ljust(20)} '
        f'Items = {result_size}. Average time: {str(mean(time_measurements))} secs')


def combine_generator(number_of_repetitions, sexes, random_actresses, random_actors):
    time_measurements = []
    for i in range(number_of_repetitions):
        actors = random_actors[:]
        actresses = random_actresses[:]
        result = []
        t0 = time.time()

        mf = {'M': iter(actors), 'F': iter(actresses)}
        for sex in sexes:
            person = next(mf[sex])
            result.append((sex, person))

        time_one_round = time.time() - t0
        time_measurements.append(time_one_round)

    print(
        f'{inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name.ljust(20)} '
        f'Items = {result_size}. Average time: {str(mean(time_measurements))} secs')


def combine_frames(number_of_repetitions, sexes, random_actresses, random_actors):
    time_measurements = []
    for i in range(number_of_repetitions):
        actors = random_actors[:]
        actresses = random_actresses[:]
        result = []
        df_actresses = pd.DataFrame(actresses, columns=['name'])
        df_actors = pd.DataFrame(actors, columns=['name'])

        t0 = time.time()

        df_actresses['sex'] = 'F'
        df_actors['sex'] = 'M'

        df = pd.concat([df_actresses, df_actors], axis=0)

        # if you really need it to be a list
        # result = df.values.tolist()

        time_one_round = time.time() - t0
        time_measurements.append(time_one_round)

    print(
        f'{inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name.ljust(20)} '
        f'Items = {result_size}. Average time: {str(mean(time_measurements))} secs')


g_sexes, g_actresses, g_actors = init()
combine_with_pop(g_number_of_repetitions, g_sexes, g_actresses, g_actors)
combine_without_pop(g_number_of_repetitions, g_sexes, g_actresses, g_actors)
combine_dict(g_number_of_repetitions, g_sexes, g_actresses, g_actors)
combine_generator(g_number_of_repetitions, g_sexes, g_actresses, g_actors)
combine_frames(g_number_of_repetitions, g_sexes, g_actresses, g_actors)
```