# Merge sort string and local variable issue

Tags: python, mergesort

I'm quite unfamiliar with Python and decided to practice some algorithms here is my implementation of the merge sort, I'm not too sure why I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 44, in <module>
   
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mid' referenced before assignment
```

```
a = [1,2,3,5,3,1,8,4,5,6]

def mergesort(x):
    n = len(x)
    if n > 1:
        mid = (n//2)
        left = x[:mid]
        right =x[mid:]
    for i in range(0, mid -1):
        left[i] = x[i]
    for i in range(mid, n-1):
        right[i - mid] = x[i]
    mergesort(left)
    mergesort(right)
    merge(left,right,x)
```

Comment: don't use semicolons at the end of lines

Comment: All this comes down to an indentation problem. Correct indentation is crucial in Python.

Comment: Python can only tell that there's a code path in your function that might try to use `mid` before any value had ever been assigned to it — so just define it by assigning something to it (like `None`) at the very beginning and the error should go away.

Comment: merge is not defined in your code, could you show more ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment" after an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367760/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment-after-an-if-sta)

Answer (score 0):

The `if`-block only runs when `n > 1`, and `mid` is initialized in it.

When `n <= 1`, the `if-block` will not be executed, and so `mid` is not initialized. So, in any of the following lines, if you reference `mid`, the error will be thrown.

This is how I'd implement mergesort:

```py
def mergesort(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    if n <= 1:
        return lst
    else:
        left = mergesort(lst[:n//2])
        right = mergesort(lst[n//2:])
        return merge(left, right)

def merge(l1, l2):
    i, j = 0, 0
    res = []
    while i<len(l1) and j<len(l2):
        a, b = l1[i], l2[j]
        if a < b:
            res.append(a)
            i += 1
        elif a > b:
            res.append(b)
            j += 1
        else:
            res.append(a)
            res.append(b)
            i += 1
            j += 1
    return res + l1[i:] + l2[j:]
```

I tweaked the algorithm for readability. Swap out the list slicing for a more efficient approach (e.g. indexing) for speed optimisation.

Comment: how to you define merge ?

Comment: @Malo I added the `merge` function.

Comment: I tested your solution, but it removes duplicate values.

Comment: @Malo Ah I must have missed it, in the else-block, instead of just appending `a`, I need to append `b` as well. Problem is the duplicates in the same list will be merged in, but the duplicates at the separate list (at specific position of the time it is checked) will not. Fixed.

Comment: @Malo Your solution has worst case `O(N^2logN)` time. `pop(0)` takes `O(N)` time (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195625/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-popping-elements-from-list-in-python/46136638)), where `N` is the length of the list you popped from, as the remaining elements have to be shifted to left. Mergesort is expected to be in `O(NlogN)` time, otherwise it is slower than selection, insertion sort.

Comment: good point. I would need to use collections.deque (doubly linked list) to be O(1) for pop(-1) and pop(0). Moreover my code consumes the l1 and l2 lists. Which may not be good in some cases.

Comment: I timed both solution. Despite a better Big O, your solution is slower when I timed it. Results may be different depending on the initial list and number of timed iteration (100000 or 1000000).

Comment: When I run it once with a very large lists of 50000 randomized int elements, your optimized code becomes a bit faster.

Comment: @Malo Slicing slowed it down, a `for i in range` loop can be used instead to append the items, but this kills readability.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way to to this based on @Bill Ong answer:

```
a = [1,2,3,5,3,1,8,4,5,6]

def merge(lst1, lst2):
## merges two sorted lists with same length +/-1
    res = []
    while lst1 and lst2:
        if lst1[0] < lst2[0]:
            res.append(lst1.pop(0))
        else:
            res.append(lst2.pop(0))
    return res+lst1+lst2


def mergesort(lst):
    n=len(lst)
    if n <= 1:
        return lst
    return merge(mergesort(lst[:n//2]), mergesort(lst[n//2:]))

print(mergesort(a))
```

Output is:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 8]
```